# Azure Active Directory Sign In automatically across multiple domains

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

We have multiple web-applications, each of them currently has an AppRegistration (unique clientId) in Azure Active Directory. What I would like to do is for when a user logs into one application, and then visits another application, they should be automatically signed into the 2nd app.

I have tried using the same CLientId between the 2 apps and currently I have set it up to use the same domain, but different sub-domains to try and make it work and it still doesnt work (app1.mydomain.com and app2.mydomain.com).

The code I am using is: https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/blob/master/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/Startup.cs

I have tried other samples and not one of them allows this to work. Wondering what I am missing.

Comment: Well, I would advise against sharing client ids. You can either a) make your signin cookie work across all your apps or b) do login separately but allow SSO to do its magic. Because of Single Sign On, the users wouldn't actually have to login again most of the time. It's only a redirect and they will be back in your app.

Comment: My plan is to use separate clientIds, but because that didnt work, I started trying with a single clientid. But SSO is not doing its magic and thats the issue that I am trying to fix and need some help with. Also, wondering if you have a set of reasons as to why the clientId shouldnt be shared by apps, or when is it a good idea to share or not share (eg: if i have 20 microservices, should they all have a separate clientid)

Comment: I typically try to avoid sharing client ids as it means permissions given to the app are also shared. And we don't really want other parts of the application to have the same permissions. Microservices are one case where sharing could be okay since the services might be parts of a larger app.

Comment: I'm curious why the SSO doesn't work though? Typically with default parameters it works quite well. Is the user required to consent to permissions?